# How can I use JPEGoptim library in pyCharm that requires libJPEG

Tags: python, image, libjpeg, jpegoptim

I want to manipulate images from my PC having windows 7 32 bit and working on python with pycharm IDE. I came to library (jpegOPTIM) that I need for my project.
But according to their installation page i need to install libjpeg before using their python bundle as described on their homepage (https://pypi.org/project/pyjpegoptim/)
The question is **How can I install libjpeg in my windows 7**(AS I haven't found any python package of libnjpeg). So that I can use jpegoptim python package on my python file.

Comment: `libjpeg` is NOT python package but library (create with C/C++) which you have to find on your own.

Comment: I found with Google: http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/ but this can be source code in C/C++ and it may need compiler C/C++.

Comment: Wikipedia: [libjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg) - there are links also to other source code - ie. [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) (FIrefox) version. As I rember Google has own version but I don't know if only source code or precompiled.

Comment: I need instructions regarding "How to use it in python"

Comment: you may need only install it in system (somewhere in Windows directories) like any other C/C++ library.

Comment: I checked source code for this `pyjpegoptim` and there is code in C/C++ so it needs compilator `C/C++` and `libjpeg` as source code (not precompiler). I don't know what you want to do with images but maybe you should use Python module `pillow` or [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/) (which use tool [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)) and they may work with JPEG. This `pyjpegoptim` is almost 10 years old and it may have problem with current Python.

Comment: ok, I will check it!